# Is it possible to change table row colour if it contains a certain value in a gsp?

Tags: grails, groovy, styling, gsp

I have a table in a gsp containing 10 deiiferent values :

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<tr>
    <th scope="row">Name:</th>
    <td>
        ${person.name}
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th scope="row">Address:</th>
    <td>
        ${person.address}
    </td>
</tr>............
```

I need to highlight (either change the background or text clour on some of the values if they are present in an array also available in the gsp.

Is this possible? For example using g:if? Like :

```
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Name:</th>
    <td>
               <g:if ${array}.contains("${person.name}")>
        //change styling of this cell
                   ${person.name}
                </g:if>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, but I've not tried it:

```
<td class="${array.contains( person.name ) ? 'highlight' : ''}">
```

So if it contains the name, then a 'highlight' class will be added to the `td`

Comment: I'd probably have a custom taglib do pretty much the same thing, but this works too.

Comment: thanks, the logic works..I don't really understand what you mean by a highlight class? is it something I need to decalre in css?

Comment: @Travis yeah you'd need to define it in css somewhere `.highlight { background-color: red }` or something less garish ;-)