# change grails row color depending on if it contains a value gsp

Tags: grails, styling, gsp

This question is similar to [Is it possible to change table row colour if it contains a certain value in a gsp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16567114/is-it-possible-to-change-table-row-colour-if-it-contains-a-certain-value-in-a-gs) but I couldn't quite get it to work with my scenario.

In my gsp table, I would like to change the row color to red if the status is equal to "DOWN". Here's what I have:

```
            <g:each in="${compInstanceList}" status="i" var="compInstance">
                <tr class="${array.contains(comp.status=="DOWN") ? 'highlightRed' : 'highlightGreen'}">

                    <td><g:link action="show" id="${compInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: compInstance, field: "name")}</g:link></td>                
                    <td>${fieldValue(bean: compInstance, field: "status")}</td>
                </tr>
            </g:each>
```

Here's my css to change the color:

```
        .highlightRed{
        background-color: red;
        }

        .highlightGreen{
        background-color: green;
        }
```

I'm sure my problem is in the second gsp line shown. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @tim_yates, my attempt is a inspired from your solution. Any idea?

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is that `array.contains(comp.status=="DOWN")` will evaluate to false most times, since the nested expression will be false? `array.contains(false)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe is:

```
<tr class="${(compInstance.status=="DOWN") ? 'highlightRed' : 'highlightGreen'}">
```

instead of

```
<tr class="${array.contains(comp.status=="DOWN") ? 'highlightRed' : 'highlightGreen'}">
```